# how to disable secure lock in my application on android

Tags: android, locking, screen

I have an issue. I am developing an alarm clock in android. When start the activity with snooze button, wake up the screen but I can't avoid the secure lock screen (pattern,PIN). I have tried with flags `onCreate` but nothing. I have tried and with `KeyBoardManager`. I have set and the permission in `Manifest file.Exist` other way??

Thanks

Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think so, it would be an easy way to 'hack' a phone. Even the default app those this, I think it's the intended behavior